# Simple infinite while loop-- c

Tags: c, while-loop, infinite-loop

I know I should debug this myself... but believe me I've tried and I'm VERY embarrassed. I can't understand why my while loop is infinitely looping. Can anyone help?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main ( void )
{
    double milesDriven;
    double gallonsUsed;
    double totalMilesDriven;
    double totalGallonsUsed;
    float milesPerGallon;
    float totalMpG;

printf( "%s", " Enter the gallons used (-1 to end): " );
scanf( "%i", &gallonsUsed);

printf( " Enter the miles driven: " );
scanf( "%i", &milesDriven);


while ( gallonsUsed != -1 || milesDriven != -1)
{
     totalGallonsUsed += gallonsUsed;
     totalMilesDriven += milesDriven;

     milesPerGallon = ( milesDriven / gallonsUsed );
     printf( " The miles/gallon for this tank was %f\n", milesPerGallon );

     printf( "%s", " Enter the gallons used (-1 to end): " );
     scanf( "%i", &gallonsUsed);

     printf( " Enter the miles driven: " );
     scanf( "%i", &milesDriven);

}


totalMpG = ( totalMilesDriven / totalGallonsUsed );
printf( " The overall average miles/gallon was %.6f\n ", totalMpG); 
return 0;    
}
```

Comment: Maybe you want that || to be && ?

Comment: Also, the scan("%i") argument is a double. Not an int. Maybe you wanted scanf("%lf", ...)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At first glance, it seems to be that you're using floating point datatypes, when you should be using integers.

```
"%i" // expects an integer
```

Try using the `int` datatype, or change your formatting to `"%lf"`

Comment: `-1` is one of those values that _can_ be represented exactly so, while your warning to be careful is apt, it's not relevant in this specific case. However, +1 since you almost certainly nailed the problem.

Comment: @paxdiablo yeah I didn't check, honestly. I'll edit my answer

Comment: Thanks! I'll admit, I'm new to C so I didn't know about the %lf for double!

Answer (score 0):

```
 while ( gallonsUsed != -1 || milesDriven != -1)
```

Here if user will enter gallonsUsed = -1 and milesDriven = 2(say), then

your above condition will be:
while(0 || 1) , which is equivalent to while(1).

Similarly if gallonUsed = 2(say) and milesDriven = -1, then

your above condition will be:
while(1 || 0) , which is again equivalent to while(1).

When both gallonUsed = -1 and milesDriven = -1

then only while(0||0) equivalent to while(0) => will be able to come out of the while loop.

Now if you wnat that if any one of (gallonUsed = -1 and milesDriven = -1), in that case, use while ( gallonsUsed != -1 && milesDriven != -1)